# Prove that $\int^b_af(x)dx=\int^b_af(a+b-t)dt$

Tags: integration

I'm having trouble with this two-part question:

> Prove that
>   $$
> \int^b_af(x)dx=\int^b_af(a+b-t)dt
> $$
>   Hence prove that, if $0<\beta<\frac{1}{2}\pi$,
>   $$
> \int^{\pi-\beta}_{\beta}\frac{\theta\space d\theta}{\sin\theta}=\pi\ln\cot\left(\frac{\beta}{2}\right)
> $$

I'm not even sure where to begin. Would somebody mind explaining how I can go about proving the above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the identity at the top, start with $x = a + b - t$. Then $$x = a \Leftrightarrow t = b \ \ \ \hbox{ and } \ \ \ x = b \Leftrightarrow t = a$$ Also $\displaystyle \frac{dx}{dt} = -1$. Thus

$$\int_a^b f(x) \ dx = -\int_b^a f(a + b - t) \ dt = \int_a^b f(a + b - t) \ dt$$

For the integral below, make the substitution $t = \beta + (\pi - \beta) - x \ $ and see what it gives you.

Comment: How does $\frac{dx}{dt}=1$? And why does $\int f(x)dx=-\int f(a+b-t)dt$? Could you add a few more steps if that's okay? :)

Comment: $x = a + b - t$, hence $dx/dt = -1$. The negative sign here is why the negative sign appears when we change variable from integrating wrt $x$ to integrating wrt $t$; i.e., $dx = (dx/dt) dt = - dt$.

Comment: Ah okay. Finally, why does $\int f(a + b-t)dt = - \int f(a + b -t)dt$?

Comment: A few people seem to have substituted $\pi - \theta$ for $\theta$ - which I can kind of understand (it seems kind of arbitrary). I'm not sure how to plug in your substitution, though...

Comment: Look at the the limits of integration. In the notation of the top results they are $a = \beta$, $b = \pi - \beta$. Hence $$x = a + b - t = \beta + (\pi - \beta) - t = \pi - t$$
So not arbitrary.

Answer (score 1):

> $a+b-t=z \implies -dt=dz$
>
> $\therefore\displaystyle\int^b_af(a+b-t)dt=-\displaystyle\int^a_bf(z)dz=\displaystyle\int^b_af(z)dz=\displaystyle\int^b_af(x)dx$

$I=\displaystyle\int^{\pi-\beta}_{\beta}\frac{\theta\space d\theta}{\sin\theta}=\displaystyle\int^{\pi-\beta}_{\beta}\frac{\pi-\theta\space}{\sin\theta}d\theta$

$$\color{red}{\therefore 2I=\pi\displaystyle\int^{\pi-\beta}_{\beta} \operatorname{cosec} \theta d\theta}$$

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\pi \operatorname{cosec} \theta \space d\theta$?

Comment: @hohner: Sorry, edited.